# What creature do these Alchemical Homunculus actions target?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, targeting, artificer

In the new version of the Artificer UA (found in [Unearthed Arcana: Artificer Revisited](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/artificer-revisited)), there is an alchemical homunculus creature. The homunculus has certain actions it can take including:

> **Buoyancy.** *The target* gains a flying speed of 10 feet for
>   10 minutes.
>
> **Inspiration.** *The target* feels giddy and effective, gaining advantage
>   on certain ability checks in the next hour. The target chooses the
>   checks before or after rolling. The magic runs out after the target
>   has used it on a number of checks equal to your Intelligence modifier
>   (minimum of 1).
>
> **Resilience.** *The target* gains a number of temporary hit points equal to
>   2d6 + your Intelligence modifier.

Who is considered "the target" of those actions? Is it the homunculus? Or can the homunculus use these abilities on other creatures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The quote you have is a set of options for an action

Note the previous paragraph (emphasis mine):

> ***Alchemical Salve (3/Day).*** The homunculus produces a salve and touches **one creature you designate**. The target receives one of the following magical benefits of your choice:

The quote you have comes right after and is only the options for this Alchemical Salve action. They can target any creature you designate, as the action suggests.

Answer (score 10):

#### The target is a creature chosen by the alchemist.

In the homunculus's stat block, it specifies special actions which require the alchemist's bonus action to activate.  The options you quoted are options of the "Alchemical Salve" special action, which targets a creature chosen by the alchemist. The homunculus must be able to touch the creature.

> Actions (Require Your Bonus Action)
>
> ---
>
> ...
>
> **Alchemical Salve (3/Day).** The homunculus produces a salve and touches one creature you designate. The target receives one of the following magical benefits of your choice:
>
> Buoyancy ...
>
> Inspiration ...
>
> Resilience ...